# How to get LUA to work in VSCode so it runs to the output window?

Tags: lua, visual-studio-code

I installed LUA by following this guide: http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLuaInWindowsForNewbies

I put LUA in Program Files(x86)>lua>5.3.5

If i open up a terminal and type 'lua' it works.

If i create a file called hello.lua with print("Hello, World!") in it, how do i run this file so it comes up in the output window of VSCode?

If i try 'start without debugging' nothing happens'. If i Terminal>Run active file/selected text, the VS terminal window says 
'print("hello, world!")
Unable to initialize device PRN'

I've obviously missed something simple but i just don't see a way to run this file to the output window, and an hour hunting through the docs and i'm none the wiser. My only other experience is with VS Community where it's just CTRL+Shift+B to complile and ALt+A to run.

Anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an extension like Lua Debug installed?(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=actboy168.lua-debug) I just installed lua debug with a fresh install of vs code and i get `hello world` to output to my debug console.

Comment: Yeah i have that. After trying it again today i noticed it throws up an error in the notifications: 'cannot find a program to debug', so i guess i've not done something that i'm meant to do. However, i installed Code Runner (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner), and it now runs lua files to the output window. So i guess i'm good to go! :-) Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension supports Lua, so you can press Ctrl-Alt-N to run the current script file. If it complains about not being able to find the executable, add this to your user settings:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "lua": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\lua\\5.3.5\\bin\\lua.exe"
}
```

Comment: Where can these settings be found?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the extension "Code Runner" in VS Code;
2. Click the gear icon and open the "Extension Settings";
3. Search for "Code-runner: Executor Map";
4. Go into `setting.json` to update the directory of the installed `lua.exe`.

   ```json
   "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "lua": "\"C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\lua.exe\"",
   }
   ```

Do not forget to add `\"` before and end of the directory.